# pytesseract cannot recognice the number 77

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I've tried all psm configs and I'm whitelisting digits only
the only number it seems to not be able to recognize for me is 77 can't figure how to make it possible
[image]

Comment: I get 77 from Tesseract 4.00 using psm 7

Comment: I'm on tesseract v5.0.0-alpha should I downgrade?